# ASAN memory leaks in embedded python interpreter in C++

Tags: python, c++, address-sanitizer

Address Sanitizer is reporting a memory leak (multiple actually) originating from an embedded python interpreter when testing some python code exposed to c++ using `pybind11`.

I have distilled the code down to nothing other than calling `PyInitialize_Ex` and then `PyFinalizeEx`

```cpp
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
    Py_InitializeEx(0);
    Py_FinalizeEx();
    return 0;
}
```

All the memory leaks originate from a call to `Py_InitializeEx`.

Example:

```
Direct leak of 576 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f0d55ce791f in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:69
    #1 0x7f0d55784a87  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so.1.0+0x133a87)
    #2 0x7f0d55769e4f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so.1.0+0x118e4f)
    #3 0x7f0d5576a084  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so.1.0+0x119084)
    #4 0x7f0d5576b0fa  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so.1.0+0x11a0fa)
    #5 0x7f0d557974e6 in PyType_Ready (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so.1.0+0x1464e6)
    #6 0x7f0d5577fea6  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so.1.0+0x12eea6)
    #7 0x7f0d5584eda5  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so.1.0+0x1fdda5)
    #8 0x7f0d559697b3  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so.1.0+0x3187b3)
    #9 0x7f0d558524e8 in Py_InitializeFromConfig (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so.1.0+0x2014e8)
    #10 0x7f0d558548fb in Py_InitializeEx (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so.1.0+0x2038fb)
    #11 0x55fe54d040ce in main /home/steve/src/test.cpp:8
    #12 0x7f0d54fe7d8f in __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
    #13 0x7f0d54fe7e3f in __libc_start_main_impl ../csu/libc-start.c:392
    #14 0x55fe54d04124 in _start (/home/steve/src/build/test+0x1124)
```

**Questions:**

- How can I free up the memory so asan is happy?
- Failing that, is it safe just to suppress `Py_InitializeEx` in its entirety?

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100773

Comment: @Red.Wave I am unable to close the question with a link to the bug report you've linked - if you would like to turn your comment into an answer I'll gladly accept

Comment: I am not a python expert. I guess someone with a more solid background should try rhat. You've got upvotes and an unanswered question is not bad for your profile.

Comment: @Red.Wave up to you - I would say it's fairly clear cut that I cannot free up the memory, as it's a bug in python (as per the linked bug report); so the only alternative is to suppress the leaks

Comment: Is there any work-arounds? That I don't know. Because the problem is very deep and old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Py_Initialize` has a long lasting known [issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100773), whose origin is in C source codes. For C++ programmers I recommend [**boost.python**](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/index.html) as a replacement that uses C++ features to simplify interoperability between the 2 languages.

Comment: These days pybind11 is probably the preferred C++ <-> python binding project. In fact it was because of embedding python in C++ that I found the leak with asan. Nevertheless your link to the issue is the answer I was looking for

Comment: I guess a it's best to not embed python. There's a tone of C++ libraries that can be adapted. The overhead would be much less. Interoperability is only meaningful on systems with affordable resources; embedded environments are not suitable in that regard. I strongly believe this is a major design flaw.